# Is it possible to stream parse an XML parent element without parsing its child elements?

Tags: xml, go

Given the following XML:

```
<Report name="scan_against_stuff">
    <ReportHost>
        ....
    </ReportHost>
    <ReportHost>
        ....
    </ReportHost>
    <ReportHost>
        ....
    </ReportHost>
    <ReportHost>
        ....
    </ReportHost>
    <ReportHost>
        ....
    </ReportHost>
</Report>
```

I would like to stream parse this XML in Go. In particular, I want to stream parse the `<ReportHost>` elements and not load them all into memory at once. The problem is that I would also like to retrieve the `name` attribute of the `<Report>` element. Why is this a problem? Well the stream parsing method that I'm familiar with would require me to parse the entire `<Report>` element, which would include all of the `<ReportHost>` elements, as they are children of the `<Report>` element. Is there any way for me to parse the parent `<Report>` element without parsing the child `<ReportHost>` elements?

### EDIT

I'm editing this for clarification in light of Volker 's comment. With the below code, the `else if ty.Local.Name == "ReportHost"` block never fires, whereas it *does* fire if the `"ty.Local.Name == "Report"` block is removed (and `else if` is changed to `if`). I *assume* that this is because once `Report` element has been processed discarded, the `ReportHost` elements which are its children are no longer available for processing.

**`parsexml.go`**

```
type ReportName struct {
    Name string `xml:"name,attr"`
}

type ReportHost struct{
   ....
}

d := xml.NewDecoder(f)
    for {
        tok, err := d.Token()
        if tok == nil || err == io.EOF {
            // EOF means we're done.
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error decoding token: %s", err)
        }
        //
        switch element := tok.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            if element.Name.Local == "Report" {
                if err = d.DecodeElement(&reportName, &element); err != nil {
                    log.Fatalf("Error decoding item: %s", err)
                }
            else if element.Name.Local == "ReportHost" {
                if err = d.DecodeElement(&reportHost, &element); err != nil {
                    log.Fatalf("Error decoding item: %s", err)
                }
            }
```

Comment: You are processing each element one by one with your code. "I want to stream parse the <ReportHost> elements and not load them all into memory at once." That is what your code does. You are not loading them all into memory all at once. What actual problem do you have?

Comment: This code parses the whole `Report` element at once, including the `ReportHost` elements. I know that I can fix that by changing `if element.Name.Local == "Report"` to `if element.Name.Local == "ReportHost"`, but then I can't get the `name` attribute of the `Report` element.

Comment: "This code parses the whole Report element at once" Why do you think that. This statement is just wrong.

Comment: @Volker see edit for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decode methods slurp up all the children of the element. To stream through the children of an element, access the element's attributes directly instead of using decode.

```
    switch element := tok.(type) {
    case xml.StartElement:
        if element.Name.Local == "Report" {

            // Look for report name in attributes.
            for _, attr := range element.Attr {
                if attr.Name.Local == "name" {
                    fmt.Println("name =", attr.Value)
                }
            }

        } else if element.Name.Local == "ReportHost" {
            var reportHost ReportHost
            if err = d.DecodeElement(&reportHost, &element); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Error decoding item: %s", err)
            }
            fmt.Println("host =", reportHost.Data)
        }
    }
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KNUGQRGrlqq).

Comment: perfect! that's exactly what I needed. Extremely helpful.